# How to I string the Last Line text in MultiLine text box if I key the Enter

Tags: c#, text, textbox, multiline

Please Show me how to I string last line text, in the Multi Line text if i Key the Enter?

```
  private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){ if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){  string sor = ...}
```

Comment: Please show me what I can string it!

Comment: What does this mean? What do you want to happen when you press enter (and please don't write "how to I string last line" - I couldn't understand what you meant by this)

Comment: I mean What I string in the multiLine textbox the Last line text! How to you dont know what are this mean?

Comment: Because it's English words, but put in some random order; it doesn't make sense. I'm fairly good at figuring out what people mean but "what I string" means nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to find the last line in a multi line text box:

```
if(textbox1.Lines.Length>0){
    string lastLine = textbox1.Lines[textbox1.Lines.Length-1];

    //put more code here

}
```